# Angular 4 - Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm having a problem when I launch my Angular app on my browser. Everything works code speaking but I'm still getting this error:

> Found the synthetic property `@routerAnimations`. Please include either
> `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` in your
> application.

I already checked the posts on this subject and there's quite a lot but all of them answered the same:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

and include it in the app module's imports.

```
imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ... 
]
```

That's what I did but still got the same error. I've been looking for hours for this solution. Anyone knows what could fix it ? Thanks

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-bc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

#### Components : *copied from answer*

```html
<div [@routerAnimations]="myOutlet.state">
    <router-outlet #myOutlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: you also need to add the `BrowserModule` have you

Comment: Yes I did, it's already there when you generate the project with angular-cli

Comment: check if you have animations installed in your package.json

Comment: Yes sir it's there, to be sure i even deleted the node_modules folder and ran "npm install"

Comment: can you please add your package.json and no sir please

Comment: Do you use Angular CLI? You should clean the cache and re-install Angular CLI.

Comment: Yes I used angular-cli to create the project

Comment: @HaHoang I did all that but still got the same error...

Comment: I'm not sure but you still get the error when you create new project using angular-cli?

Comment: @Messerschmitt could you show your code for  using @routerAnimations?

Comment: @HaHoang I just posted the solution to the mistake I made. Thanks man anyway I appreciate it

Answer (score -12, accepted):

I solved the issue, the problem was the "@routerAnimations" in my app.component.html:

```
<div [@routerAnimations]="myOutlet.state">
    <router-outlet #myOutlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

When I removed it, everything worked just fine

Comment: removing synthetic property do not solve your actual issue. since, you need that, hence, you added `BrowserAnimationsModule` at first place.

Answer (score 36):

Adding the lines

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

and

```
imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ... 
]
```

to `app.module.ts` actually solves it

Answer (score 2):

One point is definitely you need to add `BrowsersAnimationModule` in your active Module. But apart from that you need to mention `animations` for that Synthetic selector (here `@routerAnimations`) which is Angular Component Meta

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-grid',
  templateUrl: './card-grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-grid.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('routerAnimations', [
      state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0' })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],
```

Response in comment if you still have any doubts

Answer (score 2):

Sidenav won't work unless you import BrowserAnimationsModule. So import it from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using Angular 17 in mode: standalone. To solve the problem a use the flowing script in the main.ts file, based on the link: https://angular.io/guide/animations

```type-script
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideAnimations(),
  ]
});
```

Hope this script be helpful for someone.