# ngx-spinner is not hiding out after timeout

Tags: angular

**ngx-spinner is not hiding after time out. It is showing for infinite time**

**In app.component.ts**

```
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';

constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {}

ngOnInit(){
    this.spinner.show();
    setTimeout(() => {

        this.spinner.hide();
    }, 5000);
  }
```

**In app.component.html**

```
<ngx-spinner> </ngx-spinner>
```

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: Works only if you delay spinner.show(), check here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-negfop

Comment: The above code is working fine with ngx-spinner@6.1.2 version

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with latest version of ngx-spinner(v7+), It is Working fine with 6.1.2 version.

Comment: Do you think that this actually answers your question? If not and it is more of an addendum then please eidt the question and delete this non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide name for spinner to ngx-spinner v7+.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, if you check your console, you might find this error message "BrowserAnimationsModule” or “NoopAnimationsModule” in your application", this is solved in this thread [stackoverflow: How to include BrowserAnimationModule in your Angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683027/angular-4-please-include-either-browseranimationsmodule-or-noopanimationsmo)
If you follow those steps, everything should work just fine.